# Start an array at an initial size of 3 elements. Dynamically increase the array size if more then 3 elements are entered

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me how to code an **string** array at an initial size of 3 elements, then Dynamically increase the array size if more then 3 elements are entered?

Comment: someone did it already. use `std::vector<std::string>` and use your time to code more interesting stuff :P

Comment: If you are talking about an std::array, it's supposed to be fixed so it shouldn't be possible. If you are talking about programming it from scratch, indeed have a look at std::vector<std::string>!

Comment: As @tobi303 said, it already exists in the STL. If you want/need to create your own implementation (e.g.: for an assignment) you need to show what you tried to do first and where exactly you are having problems

Comment: then please be aware that the rules in your class are not realistic ones, but they are made up to make you learn something. In this case the aim is **not** to familiarize with standard c++ solutions, but to struggle and implement a basic dynamic array on your own. You should mention such requirements in the question

Answer (score 2):

Like it says in the comments use `std::vector<std::string>`

We're not going to code your algorithm for you. But using `vector` will make your life a lot easier!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use STL(If it is a homework). check realloc for changing your array's size.

```
char* text = malloc(5*sizeof(char)); //size 5
text = realloc(text, 10*sizeof(char)); //size 10
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/

But always use STL if you can!